# Drillup in highcharts from rCharts

Tags: r, rcharts, drilldown

I want to use the drilldown possibility of highcharts in rCharts. There is an example in the demo section but the return to top level button does not show up. Is there a workaround for this?

The same question was asked on github: https://github.com/ramnathv/rCharts/issues/602

Working example (at least drilldown) from the rCharts github page:

```
## Example 9 (not working properly)
drill_function <- "#! function() {
    var drilldown = this.drilldown;
    function setChart(name, categories, data, color) {
        chart.xAxis[0].setCategories(categories, false);
        chart.series[0].remove(false);
        chart.addSeries({
            name: name,
            data: data,
            color: color || 'black'
        }, false);
        chart.redraw();
    };
    if (drilldown) { // drill down
        setChart(drilldown.name, drilldown.categories, drilldown.data, drilldown.color);
    } else { // restore
        setChart(name, categories, data);
    }
} !#"

a <- rCharts::Highcharts$new()
a$chart(type = "column")
a$series(data = list(
    list(y = 15, drilldown = list(data = c(1, 2, 3))), 
    list(y = 20, drilldown = list(data = c(1, 2, 3)))), name = "test")
a$xAxis(categories = c("Brand A", "Brand B"))
a$plotOptions(column = list(cursor = 'pointer', point = list(events = list(click = drill_function))))
a
```

Answer (score 1):

Ok I found a dirty hack to achieve a drillUp(). The basic idea is to simply reload the page. The drill_function should be modified like this:

```
drill_function <- "#! function() {
    var drilldown = this.drilldown;
    function setChart(name, categories, data, color) {
    chart.xAxis[0].setCategories(categories, false);
        chart.series[0].remove(false);
        chart.addSeries({
            name: name,
            data: data,
            color: color
        }, false);
        chart.redraw();
    };
    if (drilldown) { // drill down
        setChart(drilldown.name, drilldown.categories, drilldown.data);
    } else { // restore
        location.reload(); // <- this one reloads the page!
        //setChart(name, categories, data, );
    }
} !#"
```

Comment: Nice solution. But refreshing could be horrible if you insert this chart to your shiny app or slidify presentation

Comment: That is true. If anyone has a better idea. I would like to hear it :)

Comment: If I use this script on a knit html page with multiple charts, the other charts and customizations I made by e.g. zooming are not influenced. They consist after the drillup.